# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre static y final?

Tags: java

He buscado por Internet pero no me ha quedado muy claro lo que significan estas palabras reservadas y qué funcionalidades tienen en una clase:

- **static**
- **final**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Al usar la palabra reservada `static` la declaración de la constante ha de realizarse obligatoriamente en cabecera de la clase.

Si tratamos de incorporarlo en un método obtendremos un error.

**Este ejemplo no compila:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        static final double PI = 3.1416;
    }
}
```

**pero este si:**

```
class Ideone
{
    static final double PI = 3.1416;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(Ideone.PI);
    }
}
```

Por eso dentro del método `main` al ser este un método de clase y llevar incorporado `static` en su declaración no podemos declarar constantes de clase.

---

Pero `final` si que puede ser usado dentro de métodos ademas también dentro del método `main`.

**Ejemplo:** `final double PI = 3.1416;` es valida dentro de un método.

Ademas `final double PI = 3.1416;` se puede usar para tener acceso a unos datos que sabes que en teoría no pueden ser modificados una vez sea declarados/inicializados con un valor.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final double PI = 3.1416;
    }
}
```

---

Los miembros static puedes llamarlos sin tener que crear una instancia de la misma, por ejemplo cuando usas `new MiClase` ... `miClase.a`. Ahora podrías hacer MiClase.a sin tener que usar o crear una instancia de la misma.

```
class MiClass{

  static int a; // Puedes acceder sin crear una instancia por ejemplo MiClass.a 
  final double PI = 3.1416

}
```

---

Al hacer una clase `static` esta puede ser llamada, osea puedes usar por ejemplo sus métodos sin tener que crear una instancia de la misma, por ejemplo cuando usas `new MiClase` ... `miClase.miMetodo();`. Ahora podrias hacer `MiClaseEstatica.miMetodo();` sin tener que usar o crear una instancia de la misma.

*Java no tiene manera de hacer una clase de nivel superior estática* puede hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
public final class MiClaseEstatica {
    static public int sumar (int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
}
//...
System.out.println(MiClaseEstatica.sumar(3, 2));
```

Aquí hacemos uso de una llamada estática sin necesidad de crear una instancia para acceder por ejemplo algún método de la clase.

Se vendría a ahorra algo como:

```
public MiClase miClase = new MiClase();
System.out.println(MiClase.sumar(3, 2));
```

---

Puede que le interese leer esta [pregunta/respuesta](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)

---

Las clases internas pueden ser declaradas estáticas.

se creara un *.class* por cada una de estas clases internas.

```
public class Obj {

    private int data1;
    private String data2;

    public Obj(int data1, String data2) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
    }

    private static class ObjComp implements Comparator<Obj> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Obj obj1, Obj obj2) {
            return obj2.data1 - obj1.data1;
        }

    }
}
```

también se pueden crear bloques de código como estáticos para que sean ejecutados cuando se cargue la clase.

se suelen conocer como (static initializer block) si no es declarado de forma explicita el compilador JIT (just-in-time) combina todos los campos estáticos en un bloque y los ejecuta durante la carga de clases.

```
public class Obj {

    private static int data1;

    static {
        data1 = 10;
    }
```

Los bloques de inicialización pueden ser, sustituidos por métodos estáticos como en el siguiente ejemplo puede ver:

```
public class Obj {

    private static int data1 = inicializacionDeCampo();

    private static int inicializacionDeCampo() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

se puede aplicar esta lógica de inicialización de variables de clase `static` sin necesidad de incluirlo en su constructor de clase.

static permite el acceso a métodos, variables de clase sin la necesidad de instanciar un objeto de la clase en cuestión, suele ser usado por ejemplo para la creación de clases de utilidad. Java cuenta con varias de estas como pueden ser:

- [java.lang.String](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)
- [java.lang.Math](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java)

Entonces los miembros `static` pertenecen a la clase en lugar de una instancia en concreto, esto es clave para entender mas rápido lo siguiente:

Solo existirá un campo `static` aunque se creasen miles de instancias de la clase, y aun mas a tener encuentra aunque "no exista" ninguna instancia de la misma.

Con lo que ese campo sera compartido por todas las instancias.

Esto si se analiza un poco tiene bastante sentido, tanto para lo anterior como aplicándose a métodos estáticos. Cuando se dice que no pueden referirse a miembros de una instancia, porque de ser así a que instancia se esta refiriendo cuando todas comparte el mismo campo o método estático.

Que no es lo mismo que acceder a través de una instancia específica.

**Ejemplo:**

```
public class Obj {

    private static boolean data3;
    private boolean data4Instancia;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        data3 = true; //un método estático accediendo al campo estático

        Obj instancia = new Obj();

        instancia.data4Instancia = true; //un método estático acceda a un campo no estático de una instancia especifica, aquí le decimos de alguna manera oye esta es la instancia a la que quiero acceder.

    }
```

Todo esto tiene sentido pues los valores, campos, métodos NO estáticos  dependen de la creación de instancias de la clase.

Cuando se dice que solo existirá un campo estático, es verdad a medias, pero dependiendo del nivel al que se esta explicando puede ser mas valido o menos valido, por ejemplo puede ser uno por [`Class Loader`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_classloader) por o el [hilo (thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), entre otros casos, solo lo menciono para que se tenga encuentra en cierta manera, por si se quiere profundizar en ello.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html

Comment: Toma tu tiempo :) Quieres incorporar los clases interiores estáticos, o lo hago yo?

Comment: @StefanNolde gracias por  tu comprencion es que estoy un poco liado y tuve que dejarla a media, si quieres mira mi respuesta y amplia tu la tuya, la verdad es que me haces un favor. P.D: en tu pregunta dices *Clases declarados como final no pueden ser usado como superclases.* se me olvidaba el mencionar eso que Una clase declarada final impide que pueda ser superclase de otras clases, muy bueno.

Comment: Eso fue la idea, trabajar en equipo ;) Voy a leer que escribiste hasta ahora, con temas tan fundamentales es bueno de tener más que una pregunta correcta, con distintos niveles de detalles.

Comment: @Stefan Nolde yo vote mas uno en la tuya entre otras cosas porque para serte sincero es probable que yo no hubiera mencionado lo que tu comentas sobre de si una clase es declarada como final. Saludos. P.D: y gracias de nuevo por la comprencion tanto es asi que me acabo de dar cuenta que hasta deje una respuesta en meta a la mitad XD.

Comment: Y que pasa si junto "static final" ¿Se mezcla todas sus funcionalidades sin perder sus cualidades de cada uno?

Comment: Si, @TripleX. las cualidades no cambian combinando los modificadores. La combinación en si aun tiene su usos especiales.

Comment: Vale gracias por la INFO @StefanNolde.

Answer (score 21):

Los modificadores `static` y `final` tienen contextos completamente distintos.

**static**

El modificador `static` implica que algo se define en el contexto general, **no** en un contexto de un objeto. Sin este modificador, variables, clases o campos siempre existen en el contexto de una instancia de un objeto en particular.

- Campos definidos `static` son variables globales.
- Métodos definidos `static` son funciones globales.
- Clases interiores declarado `static` funcionan como clases normales, pueden ser instados desde fuera de la clase que los contienen y (obviamente) no tienen el mismo acceso a variables y métodos de objetos instados de la clase contenedora.

**final**

Final en general significa inmutable. Hay dos usos principales:

- Variables declarados como **final** no pueden ser sobreescrito. Eso no significa que un objeto que fue asignado a una variable final no puede ser modificado en sus campos o por sus métodos, solamente significa que la referencia de esta variable a este mismo objeto nunca cambiará.
- Clases declarados como **final** no pueden ser usado como superclases. `String` por ejemplo es una clase definido como final, así no es posible de declarar un `MegaString extends String` - Java no lo permite. En forma parecida, métodos declarados como final no pueden ser sobreescrito por @Override.

***Usos comunes de `static`***

- Constantes (en combinación con `final`):

  `public static final int RESULT_CANCELED=0;`
- Singletons (objetos de que se debería usar una sola instancia):

  `public static final SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom();`
- Variables globales:

  `private static int numLusers=0;`
- Métodos globales:

  `public static Luser newInstance(){
        numLusers++;
        return new Luser();
  }`
- Clases internos públicos

  ```
  public class Almacenamiento{

     public static class AlmacenamientoCreateHelper{
        ...
   }
   ...
  }
  ```

¿Pero si una clase interna declarado `static` no tiene acceso directo a métodos y campos de la clase exterior, que es la ventaja de declarar una clase interna así?

Es un tema de organisación y probablemente existe una variedad de opiniones sobre eso. personalmente prefiero agrupar clases por paquetes para organizarlos, sin embargo se presenta una ventaja obvia: Si mantengo clases que son altamente dependiente en su código, manteniendolos en el mismo archivo ayuda mucho en evitar errores por combinar clases de distintos versiones, si uso el `.java` que contiene clase exterior y interior, siempre puedo estar seguro que tengo las versiones compatibles.

***Usos comunes de `final`***

- Constantes (en combinación con `static`)

  ```
  public static final String AUTHORITY="com.snolde.app";
  ```
- Campos de "Value Objects" usados en contextos de concurrencia.

  ```
  public class LuserVO{
      public final String uname;
      public final int uid;
      public final Token authToken;
      public LuserVO(String uname, int uid, Token auth);
  }
  ```
- Variables locales par uso en clases anónimas:

  ```
  final Socket sock = server.accept();
  Task t = new Task(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
          InputStream is = sock.getInputstream();
          ...
      }
  });
  ```
- Clases finales que no deberían ser extendido:

  ```
   public final class AuthToken{
       ...
       public boolean hasPrivilege(int pId);
   }


   // No es posible de crear una clase como esa para pasarlo a un método que acepta AuthToken:
   WeonAuthToken extends AuthToken{
       @Override
       public boolean hasPrivilege(int pId){ return true; }
   }
  ```
- Métodos que no deberían ser sobreescrito:

  ```
   protected final void onAgregado(Contexto contexto, Node padre){
       // aqui tengo código que esta llamado por otra clase de mi biblioteca
       // que es importante para el funcionamiento, y quiero evitar
       // cambios en el flujo. Después ofrezco un gancho para código
       // extendido.
   }

   protected abstract void onDespuesAgregado(Contexto contexto, Node padre);
  ```

Answer (score 10):

> **La palabra clave static se puede utilizar en 4 escenarios:**

- Variables estáticas
- Métodos estáticos
- Bloques estáticos de código.
- Clase anidada estática

---

**Veamos primeramente las variables estáticas y los métodos estáticos.**

**Variable estática**

- Es una variable que pertenece a la clase y no al objeto (instancia).
- Las variables estáticas se inicializan sólo una vez, al inicio de la ejecución. Estas variables se inicializarán primero, antes de la
  inicialización de cualquier variable de instancia
- Una sola copia para ser compartida por todas las instancias de la clase
- Una variable estática se puede acceder directamente por el nombre de la clase y no necesita ningún objeto
- Sintaxis: Class.variable

**Método estático**

Es un método que pertenece a la clase y no al objeto (instancia) Un
 método estático sólo puede acceder a los datos estáticos. No puede
 acceder a datos no estáticos (variables de instancia) a menos que
 tenga / cree una instancia de la clase. Un método estático puede
 llamar a otros métodos estáticos y no puede llamar a un método no
 estático de él a menos que tenga / crea una instancia de la clase. Un
 método estático puede ser accedido directamente por el nombre de la
 clase y no necesita ningún objeto Sintaxis: Class.methodName () Un
 método estático no puede referirse a este o super palabras clave en
 cualquier caso

**Clase estática**

- Java también tiene "clases anidadas estáticas", Una clase anidada estática es una que no implica implícitamente una referencia a una instancia de la clase externa.
- Las clases anidadas estáticas pueden tener métodos de instancia y métodos estáticos.

No hay tal cosa como una clase estática de nivel superior en Java.

> **La palabra clave final se utiliza en varios contextos diferentes para definir una entidad que no se puede cambiar posteriormente.**

- Una clase final no puede ser subclasificada. Esto se hace por razones de seguridad y eficiencia. Por consiguiente, muchas de las clases de biblioteca estándar de Java son `final`, por ejemplo `java.lang.System` y `java.lang.String`. Todos los métodos de una clase `final` son implícitamente `final`.
- Un método declarado como `final` no puede ser sobreescrito por subclases. Esto se utiliza para evitar un comportamiento inesperado de una subclase que altera un método que puede ser crucial para la función o la consistencia de la clase.
- Una variable `final` sólo se puede inicializar una vez, ya sea a través de un inicializador o una declaración de asignación. No necesita ser inicializado en el punto de la declaración: esto se llama una variable final en blanco (`blank final`). Una variable de instancia `final` en blanco de una clase debe asignarse definitivamente al final de cada constructor de la clase en la que se declara; De manera similar, una variable estática final en blanco debe asignarse definitivamente en un inicializador estático de la clase en la que se declara; De lo contrario, se producirá un error de tiempo de compilación en ambos casos.

Existe una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13772923/250260) en SO realizada por @Ashish

Answer (score 4):

A veces hacen complicado la definición de ciertas palabras claves, tratare de ser lo mas simple.

**static :**

hacer que una propiedad o método de la clase, sea propio de la clase, esto quiere decir, si tienes la clase Perro, y tienes una propiedad `color = "negro"` todos los objetos perros que creas con esta clase serán de `color = negro`, si en un momento cambias el valor a `color = "azul"`, ahora todos los objetos perros que creaste con color negro, serán azules, porque es propio de clase.

`Perro.color = "negro";` //se modifica el atributo public **static** String de la clase Perro

```
Perro perro1 = new Perro();
Perro perro2= new Perro();
// se crearon 2 perro con atributo color = "negro"
System.out.println(perro1.color); //imprime "negro"
System.out.println(perro2.color); //imprime "negro"

Perro.color = "azul"; // se modifica el atributo static
System.out.println(perro1.color); //imprime "azul"

System.out.println(perro2.color); //imprime "azul"
```

El cambio se debe a que es un atributo propio de la clase(especie) no del objeto, si cambiar un atributo propio de la clase, todos los objetos de esa clase son "afectados"

**En los métodos:** te permite llamar directamente al método sin necesidad de que exista un objeto creado.En el mismo caso del perro, si tiene un método `correr()` y no es static, solo podrías llamarlo así

```
Perro perro = new Perro();
perro.correr();// <- lo llamas desde el objeto perro creado.
```

Si fuera `static`, no es necesario tener un objeto creado, basta con llamar de la clase

```
Perro.correr() //<-- se llama desde la propia clase porque es static, propia de la clase
```

**final**

Las tipo de variable `Final`, son mas simples, solo hacen que el atributo o lo que se defina con esta palabra, no se pueda modificar.Es su valor final, sirve mayormente cuando quieres declarar CONSTANTES, valores que nunca van a cambiar.

**Nota:** las variables `static` facilitan muchas cosas, pues cuando creas elementos con este valor, pueden ser accesibles de forma fácil solo desde la clase. el atributo "final" permite solo asegurarte que el elemento es inmutable, no puede ser modificable. los atributo "static final" permiten ambas cosas, se accesibles desde cualquier parte solo desde su Clase, y son inmutables.

```
public static final double VALOR_PI = 3.1415926; 

// por convención las contantes deben ir todas en mayusculas, esto quiere decir, todas los atributos del tipo "final"
```

Answer (score 3):

Las Constantes son declaradas asi :

```
public static final String CONSTANTE = "VALOR";
```

static -> indica que es accesible a nivel de Clase y no necesita una instancia de ella para ser usada.

final -> indica que el valor una vez declarado no puede ser cambiado.

ejemplo

```
public class Clase1
{
   public static final String CONSTANTE = "VALOR";
}

    public class Clase2 {

public static void main (String[]agr)
{
    System.out.println(Clase1.CONSTANTE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Los **static** no se necesita instanciar la clase... osea `= new Clase()` para llamarlos, es simplemente llamar el método por ejemplo: `clase.metodoStatic();` ,sin requerir la instancia `Clase clase = new Clase()`, dentro de estos solo puedes usar mas métodos estáticos, ninguno de instancia.

La clase **Final** significa que no pueden tener *herencia*.

Y esa es toda la diferencia, lo demás es pura paja... información de mas.

Espero pode ayudarte, saludos.

Comment: Me gustan las respuestas simple, pero si me doy la **paja** de poner en practica que escribes, te tengo otra **información demás**: Si no uso `Clase clase = new Clase();` no tengo ningún `clase` para llamar estáticamente a `clase.metodoStatic();`. Y por supuesto puedo usar métodos no estáticos dentro de un método estático, mientras insto objetos dentro del método. Además me di la paja de leer la pregunta y me sobraba la información de mas que no se trata de comparar **métodos** estáticos con **clases** finales. El arte de ser conciso también requiere de no ser impreciso. ;)

Comment: Lo que comenta Cristina es sobre los métodos static, si el método no esta definido como static, primeramente tienes que instanciar la clase y llamar el método en la instancia. Clase clase = new Clase(); => clase.metodo(); , pero en cambio si se define el método como static se puede llamar directamente sin instanciar la clase Clase.metodo();

Comment: @StefanNolde En mi experiencia esas son las diferenciasque he encontrado  Por otra parte estos conceptos muchas veces solo se aplican en arquitecturas muy abstractas y requieren mucha acertividad,en la vida cotidiana..en el supuesto que programes Aplicaciones y no arquitecturas, ni frameworks,no le veo mucha utilidad.Si ponemos atención en las clases automáticas que ya generan los frameworks,podremos ver que ya vienen inmersa toda esa lógicaY con mi respuesta en ningún momento quise menospreciar todo el concepto,soloque es una respuesta muy compleja y enredosa para alguien que esta aprendiendo

Comment: Entonces debería haber escrito `Clase.metodoStatic()`@Jorgesys? Lo menos palabras uso para explicar algo, lo más preciso tengo que formular, o la respuesta confunde más que ayuda. Que tu entiendes lo que significa no me sorprende, porque sé que tu lo sabes suficientemente bien para explicarlo tu mismo. Pero que pasa con alguien que no tiene este base de conocimiento y busca una respuesta concisa?

Comment: @StefanNolde un poco de razón tienes, pero igual el OP se fue por la respuesta que tiene ejemplos, pensando un poco mas lejos, creo que esta pregunta se basa mas en opiniones....

Comment: La pregunta no se basa en opiniones, tal cual como se puede dar una respuesta completa y correcta que no esta basado en opiniones. La opinión entra en eso cuando empiezo a conversar cuales de los funciones de los modificadores son útiles y cuales no lo son. Yo ya me encontré con todos los usos posibles de estos modificadores, sea por usarlos yo mismo o tener que considerar los efectos de su uso en código de tercer parte.

Comment: Bien por ti @StefanNolde  felicidades :-)