# Métodos estáticos para paso por referencia

Tags: java

buenos días, tengo una duda a ver si me la podeis resolver: como en Java no se pueden pasar argumentos por referencia, entonces tengo las siguientes clases:

```
public class Matriz { //clase con métodos estáticos para operar con cualquier matriz
    public static int[][] inicializar() {
        int[][] m = new int[6][4];    
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) m[i][j] = i*j-i+j;
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static int[][] setValor(int[][] m, int x, int y, int valor) {
        if (x >= 0 && x < 6 && y >= 0 && y < 4) 
            m[x][y] = valor;
        return m;
    }

    public static int getValor(int[][] m, int x, int y) {
        int valor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if (x >= 0 && x < 6 && y >= 0 && y < 4) 
            valor = m[x][y];
        return valor;
    }
}

public class ClaseMatriz {
    private int[][] matriz;

    public ClaseMatriz() {}

    private void inicializarMatriz() {
        matriz = Matriz.inicializar();
    }

    private void setValor(int x, int y, int valor) { 
        Matriz.setValor(matriz,x,y,valor);
    }

    private int getValor(int x, int y) {
        return Matriz.getValor(matriz,x,y);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        inicializarMatriz();
        int v = getValor(3,2);
        System.out.println("Valor actual:" + v);
        setValor(3,2,5);
        v = getValor(3,2);
        System.out.println("Nuevo valor:" + v);
    }
}
```

El método inicializarMatriz de la clase ClaseMatriz funciona bien porque me devuelve la matriz inicializada... pero los otros dos métodos (setValor y getValor) no funcionan (siempre me acaba dando excepción de puntero nulo, o lo que es lo mismo, NullPointerException), ¿alguien me puede dar una orientación de por qué no funciona?

Comment: Creo que te estás confundiendo: 1) en lo del paso de argumentos, es cierto que siempre se pasan por copia, pero cuando pasas una referencia a un objeto lo que se copia es la referencia, no el objeto (desde el método llamado accedes al objeto original) 2) el hecho de que el método sea estático no supone ningún cambio al respecto y 3) se deben evitar en lo posible los métodos estáticos ya que no casan bien con la POO. En este ejemplo, lo normal sería que la lógica que tienes en `Matriz` estuviera en `ClaseMatriz`, con el array siendo una propiedad de la instancia.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que estás llamando de forma estática a la clase `ClaseMatriz`, la cual no es estática.

Para que te funcione, tienes que instanciar la clase e invocar los métodos mediante la variable creada:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    ClaseMatriz cm = new ClaseMatriz();
    cm.inicializarMatriz();
    int v = cm.getValor(3,2);
    System.out.println("Valor actual:" + v);
    cm.setValor(3,2,5);
    v = cm.getValor(3,2);
    System.out.println("Nuevo valor:" + v);
}
```

Si por el contrario, lo que quieres es llamar estáticamente a `ClaseMatriz` deberás definir todos los métodos y propiedades como estáticas.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, aunque a mi me da error concretamente en el método estático 'getValor' de la clase Matriz, me tira una excepción del tipo NullPointerException.

Comment: Has probado los cambios en el `main()` que te he propuesto? Yo lo he probado y me funciona: Devuelve 5 tanto en actual como en nuevo (si hago set a otro valor, también lo muestra en nuevo)

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que esta linea `inicializarMatriz();` le puede esta diciendo algo como esto;

public class ClaseMatriz {

```
private void inicializarMatriz() {
    matriz = Matriz.inicializar();
}
//..

public static void main(String args[]) {
    inicializarMatriz(); <--
//..
```

> non-static method inicializarMatriz(); cannot be referenced from a
>   static context

dejare una pregunta en la que se trata este tema -> el tema de static [¿Cual es la diferencia entre static y final?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49967/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-static-y-final/) tienes montones de respuesta que se complementan unas con otras en algunos casos.

---

Ahora pienso que usted esta haciendo un envoltura un tanto extraña (pero quizas no y la necesite de verdad).

```
    /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int[][] matriz;

        matriz = Matriz.inicializar();

        int v = Matriz.getValor(matriz,3,2);
        System.out.println("Valor actual:" + v);
        Matriz.setValor(matriz,3,2,7); //se cambia el 5 por el 7 pues antes era el mismo valor y podria confundir
        v = Matriz.getValor(matriz,3,2);
        System.out.println("Nuevo valor:" + v);
    }
}
class Matriz{
    public static int[][] inicializar() {
        int[][] m = new int[6][4];    
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) m[i][j] = i*j-i+j;
        }
        return m;
    }

    public static void setValor(int[][] m, int x, int y, int valor) { //aqui se quita el retorno
        if (x >= 0 && x < 6 && y >= 0 && y < 4) 
            m[x][y] = valor;
    }

    public static int getValor(int[][] m, int x, int y) {
        int valor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        if (x >= 0 && x < 6 && y >= 0 && y < 4) 
            valor = m[x][y];
        return valor;
    }
}
```

¿Lo anterior no funciona como espera? (quizas sea yo que es muy tarde y se me este pasando algo)

---

ClaseMatriz en este ejemplo se sustituye por Ideone (pues esta adaptado para un ide online)