# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una variable final y una variable static final?

Tags: java

tengo un ejercicio que no logro comprender del todo, si bien llego a formular una respuesta no sé cómo ejemplificar ni creo que mi respuesta sea 100% correcta.
¿Podrían ayudarme con esto por favor?

*¿Cuál es la diferencia entre una variable final y una variable static final? Muestre ejemplos y explique.*

Desde ya muchas gracias <3

Comment: Una pregunta similar en la versión en Inglés ya habia sido hecha espero te sirva la información

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563652/static-final-variable-in-java

Comment: Ya se formuló una [pregunta parecida en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49967/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-static-y-final) , hasta podría ser un duplicado 3:)

Comment: Bueno, en el primer caso está en inglés y solo busqué en el sitio en español, en el segundo caso, esa pregunta no es la misma, pregunta la diferencia entre static y final y mi pregunta es más concreta pero gracias de todos modos.

Comment: @ShadowPaz la gracia de [es.so] es tener las respuestas **en español**. Para enlazar con la versión inglesa dejamos de mantener la versión en español...

Answer (score 4):

La palabra clave `final` es usada para definir variables a las cuales solo se les puede asignar valor una vez.

```
public class Ejemplo{
  public final int variable;

  public Ejemplo(int parametro)
  {
    variable = parametro;
  }
}

Ejemplo primerEjemplo  = new Ejemplo(1); //Le asigno un valor

//Ya contiene un valor y no puedes volver a asignarle uno
//primerEjemplo.Variable = 2;

//Sin embargo, cada objeto creado en base a dicha clase 
//puede contener un valor diferente en las variables 
//que hacen uso de la palabra final

Ejemplo segundoEjemplo  = new Ejemplo(100);

System.out.println(primerEjemplo.Variable); // 1
System.out.println(segundoEjemplo.Variable); // 100
```

Mientras que a la combinación de `static` y `final` se le conoce como variable constante, la cual conserva su valor a travez de diferentes objetos y no se le puede asignar un valor por fuera de la clase en la que fue creada.

```
public class Ejemplo{
  public static final int Variable = 10;

  public Ejemplo(int parametro)
  {
    Variable = parametro;
  }
}

Ejemplo primerEjemplo  = new Ejemplo();
Ejemplo segundoEjemplo  = new Ejemplo();

//Mientras que cada objeto creado en base a dicha clase
//Contienen el mismo valor en sus constantes
System.out.print(primerEjemplo.Variable); //10
System.out.print(segundoEjemplo.Variable); //10
```

Answer (score 0):

## La teoría

Voy a responder con lo que dice la especificación del lenguaje Java:

### [`final`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

Una variable final solo se puede asignar una vez.

Estás variables observan las  normas establecidas en el apartado [§16 Asignación Definitiva](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-16.html) de la especificación, lo cual quiere decir que:

- La variable debe asignarse definitivamente antes del acceso, o se produce un error en tiempo de compilación.
- Para cada asignación a una variable final en blanco, la variable debe estar definitivamente sin asignar antes de la asignación, o se produce un error en tiempo de compilación.
- Una variable de instancia final en blanco debe asignarse definitivamente y, además, no debe asignarse definitivamente al final de cada constructor de la clase en la que se declara, o se produce un error en tiempo de compilación.

Una vez que se ha asignado una variable final, siempre contiene el mismo valor. Si una variable final contiene una referencia a un objeto, entonces el estado del objeto puede modificarse mediante operaciones en el objeto, pero la variable siempre se referirá al mismo objeto. Esto se aplica también a las matrices, porque las matrices son objetos; si una variable final contiene una referencia a una matriz, los componentes de la matriz pueden modificarse mediante operaciones en la matriz, pero la variable siempre se referirá a la misma matriz.

Una final en blanco es una variable final cuya declaración carece de un inicializador.

Una variable constante es una variable final de tipo primitivo o tipo String que se inicializa con una expresión constante (§15.28). Que una variable sea o no una variable constante puede tener implicaciones con respecto a la inicialización de clase (§12.4.1), la compatibilidad binaria (§13.1), la accesibilidad (§14.21) y la asignación definida (§16.1.1).

Tres clases de variables se declaran implícitamente finales:

- un campo de una interfaz (§9.3),
- una variable local declarada como un recurso de una declaración try-with-resources (§14.20.3)
- y un parámetro de excepción de una captura múltiple cláusula (§14.20). Un parámetro de excepción de una cláusula catch única nunca se declara implícitamente como final, pero puede ser efectivamente final.

También, ciertas variables que no se declaran `final` se consideran efectivamente tales si cumplen ciertas condiciones (para más detalles sobre esto ver la especificación).

---

### [`static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)

Si un campo se declara `static`, existe exactamente una encarnación del campo, sin importar cuántas instancias (posiblemente cero) de la clase puedan crearse. Un campo estático, a veces llamado una variable de clase, se encarna cuando la clase se inicializa (§12.4).

---

## Ejemplo práctico

Para entender la diferencia entre una variable o campo declarada como `final` y otra declarada como `static final` me voy a basar en la que es para mi, [la mejor respuesta sobre este asunto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15656208/5587982), por su simplicidad y claridad.

Y es que para comprender dicha diferencia hay que entender cuál es el comportamiento de los objetos con respecto a los constructores, métodos, variables de clase (variables estáticas) y variables de instancia.

Consideremos entonces el siguiente código:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
class Test {
    private final List foo;

    public Test() {
        foo = new ArrayList();
        foo.add("foo"); // Modification-1
    }

    public void setFoo(List foo) {
       //this.foo = foo; Aquí tendríamos error en tiempo de compilación.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
          Test t = new Test();
          t.foo.add("bar"); // Modification-2
          System.out.println("print - " + t.foo);
    }

}
```

En el código de más arriba hemos definido un constructor para la clase `Test`, con un método `setFoo()`.

#### Acerca del constructor:

el constructor solo se puede invocar una vez por creación de objeto utilizando la  palabra clave `new`. No se puede invocar el constructor varias veces, porque el constructor no está diseñado para ello.

#### Acerca del método:

se puede invocar un método tantas veces como desee (incluso nunca) y el compilador lo sabe.

#### Escenario 1

```
private final List foo;  // 1
```

`foo` es una variable de instancia. Cuando creamos el objeto de la clase `Test`, la variable de instancia `foo` se copiará dentro del objeto de la clase `Test`. Si asignamos `foo` dentro del constructor, entonces el compilador sabe que el constructor se invocará solo una vez, por lo que no hay problemas para asignarlo dentro del constructor.

Si asignamos `foo` dentro de un método, el compilador sabe que un método se puede llamar varias veces, lo que significa que el valor tendrá que cambiarse varias veces, lo que no está permitido para una variable final. ¡Entonces el compilador decide que el constructor es una buena elección! Puedes asignar un valor a una variable `final` solo una vez.

#### Escenario 2

```
private static final List foo = new ArrayList();
```

`foo` ahora es una variable estática. Cuando creamos una instancia de la clase `Test`, `foo` no se copiará al objeto porque `foo` es estático. Ahora `foo` no es una propiedad independiente de cada objeto. Esta es una propiedad de la clase `Test`. Pero `foo` puede ser visto por múltiples objetos. Cada objeto creado con la palabra clave `new` invocará al constructor de `Test` que cambia el valor en el momento de la creación de múltiples objetos.O sea, lo que ocurre en este caso es que la variable `foo, declarada` static final`, no se copia en cada objeto, sino que se comparte entre múltiples objetos. Son dos cosas totalmente distintas.

#### Escenario 3

```
t.foo.add("bar"); // Modification-2
```

En este caso, no se está cambiando el primer objeto al que se hace referencia, pero se está agregando contenido dentro de `foo`, lo cual está permitido. El compilador se queja si intentas asignar una nueva `ArrayList()` a la variable de referencia `foo`.

Aquí aplica lo que vimos en la parte teóricoa: Si has inicializado una variable `final`, entonces no puedes cambiarla para referirte a un objeto diferente. (En este caso `ArrayList`).

---

### Aparte de las variables

En cuanto a otras definiciones con respecto a `final` podríamos decir también que:

- las clases `final` no pueden ser subclasificadas
- los métodos `final` no pueden ser sobre-escritos. (Este método está en una superclase)
- los métodos finales pueden sobre-escribir. (Lee esto de forma gramatical. Este método se encuentra en una subclase)