# Quiero hacer un constructor vacio pero tengo una constante que no me deja hacerlo, me obliga a pasarlo por parametro

Tags: java

```
public class Persona {
private String nombre, ID;
private int edad;
private double peso, altura;
private final char sexo;


public Persona(char sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

 public Persona(){
    
}
```

//El error que me sale, es que no he inicializado la variable sexo. Espero me ayuden gracias comunidad :)

Comment: se debe a que estas usando la restricción final ,por eso te pide inicializar

Comment: Es que quiero pasarlo como una constante

Comment: quilate el final, mas detalle del concepto final [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148209/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-una-variable-final-y-una-variable-static-final)

Comment: Gracias bro, y también me olvide de pasarle un argumento ya establecido a la constante, será por eso el error tambien?

Comment: Aclara tus conceptos, esto: *Es que quiero pasarlo como una constante* no tiene ningún sentido. Si es una constante, defínela como tal en la clase, asignándole su valor. El concepto **constante** significa un valor que no está destinado a cambiar y que se conoce de antemano. ¿Qué sentido tiene entonces *pasarla* en el constructor? Se pasan aquellos valores que pueden cambiar, no los valores constantes, los cuales, por lo general, deberían conocerse de antemano.

Comment: Es cierto bro, gracias por aclarar los datos :), se me habia olvidado que una constante ya debe tener algo declarado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

así:

```
public class Persona {
private String nombre, ID;
private int edad;
private double peso, altura;
private char sexo;

public Persona(char sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public Persona() {
    super();
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(String iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public double getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(double peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public double getAltura() {
    return altura;
}

public void setAltura(double altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}

public char getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(char sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}
```

}

Comment: Gracias brooooo