# java - pregunta sobre final y static

Tags: java

me pueden explicar que es lo que hace o sucede en la siguiente instrucción:

```
private static final SecureRandom numerosAleatorios = new SecureRandom () ;
```

mi duda ¿como un objeto puede ser constante (final)?
¿static en la creación de un objeto?

Comment: Esto puede servirte [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49967/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-static-y-final]

Answer (score 1):

En java la palabra reservada `static` indica que los varoles se mantendran en memoria durante la ejecución de al aplicación. La palabra reservada `final` indica que los valores no pueden ser modificados posterior a su creación o asignación.

En java se puede declarar la constante y asignarla posteriormente, sin embargo si se intenta reasignar la variable (`static final`) java no lo permitira.

```
public class{
  private static final int CONSTANTE;

  public class(){
    CONSTANTE = 12345678;
    this.metodo();
  }

  private void metodo(){
    CONSTANTE = 98765; // esta asignación no es permitida y genera error
  }
}
```

Comment: isaac gracias por la ayuda,  yo entiendo y tienes la razón cuando explicas sobre static y final refiriendote a una variable de tipo primitivo int.  pero mi duda es que implica la utilización de  las palabras claves o reservadas "static y final" en la creación de un objeto o en una variable que hace referencia a una clase, en mi caso, SecureRandom.

Comment: Es igual, lo que hace es que se crea una instancia de SecureRandom y siempre que se use numerosAleatorios (por standar deberia ser `private static final SecureRandom NUMEROS_ALEATORIOS = new SecureRandom()`) siempre va a acceder a la misma instancia del objeto y adicional que posterior a su declaración no es posible hacer una nueva reasignación.

Comment: Muchas gracias isaac por la aclaración,  me surge otra pregunta, discúlpame si soy muy preguntón. Suponiendo que declare y creo al objeto numeroAleatorios sin la palabra final, ¿como podría reasignar a numerosAleatorios?

Comment: le creas una nueva instancia, `numerosAleatorios = new SecureRandom()`

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que con una instancia puedes generar varios números aleatorios y no es necesario crear una instancia por cada número aleatorio que quieras crear.

Comment: te agradezco mucho por la ayuda Isaac. Lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Un atributo declarado como `static` puede ser accedido o invocado sin la necesidad de tener que instanciar un objeto de la clase, por lo que a veces también se le conoce como variable de clase ya que todos los objetos comparten el mismo valor el cual se mantiene durante toda el ejecución del programa.

Por su parte un atributo declarado como `final` indica que solo se le puede asignar un valor u objeto una única vez, y por lo tanto su valor será siempre el mismo durante la ejecución del programa, y si se intenta cambiar marcaría error.

A continuación dejo un ejemplo donde se explica el código en los comentarios.

```
public class Constantes {
public static final double pi = 3.1416;
}

public class Main {
public static void main(args[]){
System.out.println("El valor de pi es" + Constantes.pi); ///Podemos acceder a la variable solamente escribiendo el nombre de la clase, y sin tener que crear un objeto de la clase Constates.
Constantes.pi = 34.13; /// nos marcaría error ya que su valor no puede cambiarse.
}
}
```

Comment: FrEqDe gracias por la ayuda,  yo lo entiendo y tienes la razón cuando explicas sobre static y final refiriendote a una variable de tipo primitivo double.  pero mi duda es que implica la utilización de  las palabras claves o reservadas "static y final" en la creación de un objeto o en una variable que hace referencia a una clase, en mi caso, SecureRandom.